# bash using STDIN in if-statement

Tags: bash, shell, unix, conditional-statements

Is there a way I can output an error if stdin isn't equal to a particulair file?
For example:
I want my stdin to be equal to test.txt

```
./script.sh < test.txt # should run
```

but

```
./script.sh < wrong.txt # shouldn't run
```

Is there a way to do this? Something that looks like this maybe?

```
if [ STDIN != "test.txt" ]
then 
echo "Error: stdin should be able to test.txt"
fi
```

Comment: (AFAIK) I am afraid that is not possible (in a simple way) as the redirects (pipes) are setup by the shell which runs the `./script.sh < test.txt` command. The shell process running the `script.sh` does not know what is on the other end of it's stdin pipe).

Comment: If you need a particular file, don't read from standard input; take the file name as an argument.

Comment: I admit a mistake, the answers are right. Unfortunately this approach won't work for e.g. `cat wrong.txt | ./script.sh`. The idea of using a file name argument is brilliant!

Comment: Perhaps your script should just redirect its own stdin to the correct file, rather than forcing the poor user to type it manually and then complaining when she gets it wrong. Try putting `exec < test.txt` at the beginning of the script

Comment: Yes, but the thing is I need to do the exercise exactly the way I put it. It's for school

Answer (score 4):

On `linux`, yes, but it isn't portable:

```
#in a POSIX shell:
if [ "`readlink /dev/fd/0`" != "$PWD/test.txt" ]; then 
    >&2 echo "Error: stdin should be able to test.txt"
fi
```

This works because on linux, `/dev/fd/0` (or `/proc/self/fd/0` or `/proc/$$/fd/0` (in a shell only)) is a symbolic link that points to the file that represents your stdin.

Comment: Thanks for the `/dev/fd` solution! +1 for that! Actually this is just a symlink to `/proc/self/fd`. Actually `/proc/self` itself is a symlink to `/proc/<PID>`. So everything points to `/proc/<PID>/fd`. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You has to check if file handler 0 is redirected to your file or not. You can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

me=$$
file=$(readlink -n /proc/$me/fd/0)
echo $file   
if [[ "$file" =~ /x.sh$ ]]; then echo YES
else echo NO
fi
# Alternate solution
if [[ "$file" == */x.sh ]]; then echo YES
else echo NO
fi
# Another alternate old style bash solution
# if [ "${file##*/}" = x.sh ]; then
```

At first it gets the PID of the running [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). Then if look for the file handler 0 in the virtual /proc filesystem. Every item in `/proc/<PID>fd/` is a symlink, which can be read by `readlink(1)`. If it is not redirected the symlink is linked to a dev file like this: `/dev/pts/6` if it is redirected to the terminal OR `pipe:[33773]` if it is a pipe OR `socket:[36915]` if it is a socket (like /dev/tcp/ibm.com/80) OR `/path/filename` if a file is redirected. Then the `file` has to match against a pattern. In my case I tested if the `file` equals with `x.sh`.

So the if you type

```
$ ./x.sh <x.sh; ./x.sh < y.sh
```

The output is

```
/home/truey/stackoverflow/x.sh
YES
YES
/home/truey/stackoverflow/y.sh
NO
NO
```

Comment: @Joey it matches a string against a [tag:regex].

Comment: No need for `$me`: `readlink -n /proc/$$/fd/0` works just fine.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Your are right. My version is a bit talkative! But as PSkicit mentioned `/proc/self/fd` works as well.